# Java Selenium Webdriver - sending text to field isn't triggering angularjs search field

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, webdriver

I am using the send keys function in Webdriver to send the following value:

```
WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.name("input"));
inputField.sendKeys("String of text");
```

This is supposed to trigger an angularjs function behind the scenes which will then provide me with a list of values that match the text string that has been passed.

However, this search is not being presented on screen after sending the keys. Is there anything else i need to do to allow for this interaction?

Comment: maybe you can try to lose focus from input?

Comment: I'm fairly new to selenium. What command do i use to do this?

Comment: Pass the tab key after your string  because Sendkey just sends the keys, it does nothing else.

Comment: I have tried doing the following after sending the keys but this doesn't seem to be working:
`Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.TAB);`

Comment: Have you tried using ENTER after you've passed the value.

Comment: I managed to find a solution that worked for me and have answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my own particular issue by utilising the sendKeys function and sending a number pad key through (the string i was after had a unique numeric part to it). The record was then automatically highlighted so sending the Return key selected the record and populated the value as i needed

For anyone interested, the code looks like below:

```
inputField.click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD3,Keys.NUMPAD2).build().perform();
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

There looks to be a method within this function to send keys in a unicode format, however i was not able to make that work for me but it may work for others:

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.getKeyFromUnicode("[Unicode character]"));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This method works for me:

```
public void enterTextReactJs(WebElement inputField, String value) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = '"+value+"'", inputField);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0]._valueTracker", inputField);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0]._valueTracker.setValue('xxx')", inputField);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, simulated: true }))", inputField);
}
```